# PXAttributeExtension in Acumatica

Tags: erp, acumatica

Does anybody knows how to use `PXAttributeExtension` in **Acumatica**?

Can I use it for modification of existing attributes, for example `CurrencyInfoAttribute`?

Comment: I get response from Acumatica. They added PXAttributeExtension for their internal purposes and not recommend for usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PX.Data.PXAttributeExtension has been removed as of version 5.1

Fortunately Acumatica provides a variety of ways to both override and modify existing attributes within the system, the mostly commonly used one are :

[PXMergeAttributes] - Placed on a CacheAttached handler, reuses existing attributes defined in DAC

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[NPSubaccount(typeof(APTranExtension.usrNPFundID), typeof(APTranExtension.usrNPMasterID), typeof(APTran.accountID), typeof(APTran.branchID), true)]
protected virtual void APTran_SubID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

[PXCustomizeBaseAttributeAttribute] - Placed on a CacheAttached handler, Overrides a single property on a attribute for a particular screen

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), nameof(PXUIFieldAttribute.DisplayName), "Refined Subaccount")]
protected virtual void APTran_SubID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

A great article on the methods of overriding and customizing attributes can be found here : https://www.codeday.top/2017/10/10/47532.html